Fired for running a queue worker?
I got given a task. To write a new job, that emails users about their expired media items. During testing, I had to run the job on the staging server.
The manager got an email, due to the queue worker running old jobs, which was associated with the managers email.
I then got fired due to the manager and hundreds of employees being emailed about media items that weren't even theirs.
Am I at fault? Why? Surely this is the business' problem for having real data on a testing environment? Bare in mind, I'm less than 2 months into this role.

Its completely different...

You might have better luck posting on Workplace.  Practically, the answer there will be start off "Yeah, sounds like the employer is being dumb.  But employers are generally allowed to be dumb and to fire people for silly reasons.  Learn a lesson, be more cautious next time, good luck in your next role."

(1) We can't give you legal advice on your specific situation, such as whether you were at fault or whether your firing was legal. (2) Laws about firing are dramatically different in different jurisdictions (countries / states / etc) and you haven't said where this took place.

@JustinCave We've already bumped this from The Workplace because the OP wanted to make it specifically a question about ISO 27001 violations.

Are you in a country/juristiction/contract clause where they need "cause" or "fault" to fire you? Even in highly protective Germany, you can normally be fired during your probation period without cause and very little notice.

exactly identical to this question

You did something at work that inconvenienced the entire company.  You've only been there for 2 months.  Accept that you own this problem by firing up a process that did things you were not familiar with.  Next time ask.
Unless you have protections from your country's laws or a union or other employment contract, yes, they can fire you for it.
